# #INCLUDE "BOARD.H"

Tags: c, freertos

I got the following error when compiling a C file based on `FreeRTOS` through `MCUXpresso` IDE for `LPC1769`:

> Invoking: MCU C Compiler
>
> fatal error: board.h: No such file or directory
>
> src/subdir.mk:24: recipe for target 'src/new.o' failed
>
> #include "board.h"

**Question:**

Any idea, please?

Comment: this is straight forward `board.h` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the location of board.h. It should be in the search path (current folder + system folder).

If board.h is in a different folder, consider adding -I/path/to/different/folder to the command line.